# How to use the alias of my calculated parameter (in SELECT clause) in WHERE clause with PostgreSQL to prevent repetition?

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, column-alias

In the query below, the parameter `date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE) - f.birth_year` is repeated three times. How can I replace it by its alias `age` ?

```
SELECT
    date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE) - f.birth_year AS age
FROM
    public.foo f
WHERE
    date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE) - f.birth_year >=20 AND
    date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE) - f.birth_year <=30
```

Comment: That's not the right way to get age, at least in the United States.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reuse a `select` alias in the `where` clause. You need to repeat the expression, or use a subquery or cte.

For what it's worth, you can use `between` to have the expression just once instead of twice in the `where` clause:

```
SELECT date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE) - f.birth_year AS age
FROM public.foo f
WHERE date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE) - f.birth_year BETWEEN 20 AND 30
```

As for the subquery solution, that would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE) - f.birth_year AS age
    FROM public.foo
) f
WHERE age BETWEEN 20 AND 30
```

Comment: does `BETWEEN x AND y` include `x` and `y` ?

Comment: @DevonDahon: yes, it is inclusive on both ends.

Answer (score 0):

A CTE lets you name expressions so you can avoid repeating them. By the way, that's not the correct calculation for age:

```
with data as (
    SELECT date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE) - birth_year AS age
    FROM public.foo
)
select * from data
WHERE age >= 20 AND <= 30;
```

Comment: Check out the [age](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) function.

Comment: If you haven't had your birthday yet that year it's off by one.